# How can i use custom title like this env.title in nuxt.config head?

Tags: java, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to use env.title in the nuxt.config file but the null value is in it.

vue and nuxt

```
export default {
  env: {
    TITLE: 'site-title'
  },
  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
   title: process.env.TITLE
}
}
```

Comment: I realized. best way use the $store  example:
head(){ return {title: this.$tore!=null?$this.$store.state.title : '' }}